# Autofs 770 mount point permission

Tags: automount, fuse, autofs

In `/etc/auto.sshfs` I write this:

```
-fstype=fuse,uid=worker,gid=workers,rw,allow_other [etc other options]
```

Then it correctly sets the mount point permissions to `worker:workers` when it mounts automatically. The problem is there is `allow_other` there, so other users can write into the mount point too. If I remove `allow_other` then `worker` cannot write to the mount point, even though the permissions are shown as `worker:workers` in the file system. How can I set the permissions to `worker:workers` with permissions 770?

Comment: i am also trying to lock this down, and am getting very tired of `autofs` entirely, as a result. might have to try systemd's approach

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using file_mode and dir_mode option?

-fstype=fuse,uid=worker,gid=workers,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770 ://server/share

Answer (score 0):

after losing time to the trial-and-error, inflexible syntax of `autofs`, the simple answer is: uninstall it.

there is a new, succinct `systemd` auto-mount option which can be used with `fstab` which allows you to use all the standardized mount permission options, and it looks like this:

```
  x-systemd.automount
```

an example of it in an `fstab` line:

```
  /dev/sdd1   /mnt/hitachi-one     auto     noauto,x-systemd.automount     0 2
```

the `noauto` option will mean it will not attempt to be mounted at boot, as with older software `autofs`.

after adding a new `x-systemd.automount` line to `fstab` you then need to run:

```
  sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then both, or one, of the following:

```
  sudo systemctl restart remote-fs.target
  sudo systemctl restart local-fs.target
```

for more infomation about it:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fstab#Automount_with_systemd

Comment: no i haven't designed a font before, i just use source code pro alot. the example utilizes `systemd` which is core software that is a part of almost all linux distributions nowadays, and is very likely made by completely different developers, though they clearly copied some features from `autofs` - perhaps they are trying to replace it, as `systemd` already replaces some other older core linux software. i just wanted to write something up about it, as i didn't feel i could find what i was looking for, online, for a long while